# Asymptotic behavior of $(1-1/n)^{n/\log_2 n}$

Tags: limits

I am reading Garban & Steif's book on Boolean Functions and while doing an exercise about the influence of the tribes example, with the sixe of each tribe being $\log_2n$ I need to find the asymptotical behaviour of
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}
 \right)^{n/\log_2n}.$$

I'm having trouble to determine this behaviour because of the $\log_2 n$ factor. If anyone could help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression can be written as
$$\exp\left[\left(\frac{n}{\log_2(n)}\right) \,\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right].$$
Now, using the fact that $\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, you can simplify it to
$$\exp\left[-\frac{1}{\log_2(n)}+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n\log_2(n)}\right) \right]=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\log_2(n)}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left( \frac{1}{n\log_2(n)}\right).$$

Comment: If you distribute the terms and expand the exponential multiplying the $\mathcal{O}$, I think my answer should be correct, no?

Comment: Oh, I suppose so, for some reason I thought that wouldn't work. My mistake!